# How to change the HTTP GZIP Compression Level for Dynamic Content in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, gzip, compression

I would like to change the HTTP GZIP compression level in IIS7 from 0 to 4 as mentioned in these articles:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/

However I cannot see any reference in them (or http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression) on how to change the compression level from 0 - 10.

The compression page in IIS only has tick-boxes to enable/disable dynamic and static compression.

My **Web.config** file has the line:

Please can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set it in the compression scheme:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression/scheme

for example to set it in gzip using AppCmd:

appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /[name='gzip'].dynamicCompressionLevel:"5"  /commit:apphost

Comment: By the way, one easy way is using Configuration Editor which will show you all the properties, and it can generate the scripts to set that (that is how I generated the AppCmd command above)

Comment: Hi CarlosAg, I have installed the Configuration Editor and have it open. In section system.webServer/urlCompression. Where is the option to set the level of compression? Many thanks.

Comment: Level of compression is set in system.webServer/httpCompression inside the collection, specific to the compression used (see above)